# Removing lines from Syntactic tree in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to remove the lines under the V heads (connecting V to "likes"). I've tried one solution: adding the line

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
```

which let me get replace some of the lower lines with `\\` but I can't do this universally. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.TP
    [.DP \edge[roof]; \node (J) {John}; ]
    [.T$'$
        [.T ]
        [.\emph{v}P
            [.DP \edge[roof]; \node (Jtrace) {$<$John$>$}; ]
            [.\emph{v}$'$
                [.\emph{v}
                    [.V \node(V1){likes}; ]
                    [.\emph{v} ]
                ]
                [.VP
                    [.V \node(V2){$<$likes$>$}; ]
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {Mary} ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

\draw[->] (Jtrace) [in=-90,out=-90,looseness=1.5]  to (J);
\draw[->] (V2) [in=-90,out=-90]  to (V1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Note that `qtree` is another package and not relevant here as far as I can tell. You can format code by highlighting it and clicking `{}` or using ctrl+k.

Comment: Do you want something like `no edge from parent`? (I don't really use `tikz-qtree`, so I might be getting the name wrong but take a look in the documentation.)

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use \\ universally? It works just fine for the V nodes in your example.

Comment: Specifically, `[.\node(V1){V\\likes}; ]` and `[.\node(V2){V\\$<$likes$>$}; ]` should work fine, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the construct `[.V\\\node(V1){likes};]` which I assume is what you were trying to do. As Jason notes in the comment, you can instead use `[.\node(V1){V\\likes};]` which achieves exactly what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.TP
    [.DP \edge[roof]; \node (J) {John}; ]
    [.T$'$
        [.T ]
        [.\emph{v}P
            [.DP \edge[roof]; \node (Jtrace) {$<$John$>$}; ]
            [.\emph{v}$'$
                [.\emph{v}
                    [.\node(V1){V\\likes}; ]
                    [.\emph{v} ]
                ]
                [.VP
                    [.\node(V2){V\\$<$likes$>$}; ]
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {Mary} ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[->] (Jtrace) [in=-90,out=-90,looseness=1.5]  to (J);
\draw[->] (V2) [in=-90,out=-90]  to (V1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]